# nodejs passport not logging out because of middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, passport.js

I am making a webapp using nodejs, express, mongoose and passport npm.

Earlier my login and logout functionality was working fine but now I had to add a functionality for checking if user is premium or normal user.
So I made a middleware which is now causing problem in logging out.
here are my codes.

In my index.js file an ajax request on /matchData is being called every second to get data depending on user type.

```
//ajax routes for json response
router.get('/matchData', isPremium);


//middleware causing problem
function isPremium(req,res,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        if(req.user.type=='premium'){
            console.log("user is premium");
            Match.getMatchLatestData(function(err,match){
                if(err) throw err;
                res.send(match[0]);
            });
        }else{
            console.log("user is loggedin but not premium");
            Match.getMatchData(function(err,match){
                if(err) throw err;
                res.send(match[0]);
            });
        }
    }else{
        console.log("user not logged in");
        Match.getMatchData(function(err,match){
            if(err) throw err;
            res.send(match[0]);
        }); 
    }   
}
```

and in my user.js where my login and logout functionalty is as follows

```
//Login Routes
router.get('/login',isAuthenticated2, function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('user/login',{
    title:'login'
  });
});

router.post('/login',isAuthenticated2, passport.authenticate('local',{failureRedirect:'/users/login', failureFlash:'Invalid Email Id or Password'}),function(req,res){
    console.log('Authentication Successful');
    req.flash('success','You are logged in.');
    res.redirect('/');
});

//logout route
router.get('/logout',isAuthenticated,function(req,res){
    req.logout();
    req.flash('success','You have logged out');
    res.redirect('/');
});

function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
    else{
        req.flash('error','Please Login First')
        res.redirect('/users/login');   
    }

}

function isAuthenticated2(req, res, next) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        req.flash('info','You are already logged in.')
        res.redirect('/');  
    }
    else
        return next();
}
```

now the problem is when I logout it displays flash msg successful but in my console it still shows I am logged in but not premium or I am premium, which is the only case if I am logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `req.logout()` try to use below snippet

```
req.session.destroy(function (err) {
    res.redirect('/');
 });
```

Comment: thanks this solved this problem and also another problem where back button after sign out was keeping me logged in.

Comment: one more thing how to use flash messages with it. Right now flash msg are causing error req.flash requires session although my express app is using express-session. @Urvish

Comment: 1. back button after sign out was keeping me logged in - There has to be one end point on each page where you check user is logged in or not. If user not loggedin then it should return 401 or some fix code. Write one response interceptor on client side code, if any of the response returns 401 then redirect it to login page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code as in in node we set session for user after login, destroying same will logout user

```
//logout route
router.get('/logout',function(req,res){
    req.session.user = '';
    res.redirect('/login'); // redirect wherever required
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and found answer from http://www.passportjs.org/docs/logout/

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

or in case you have a logout page.

```
   app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.logout();
    res.render('logout', {
             title: "Moi moi!"
         });

    });
```